# Do not cancel the first TRY return due to INNER TRY error

Tags: javascript, try-catch, prisma

I'm trying to send a API request.
That API request creates a document, but before it is sent to the user, another fetch method is executed that sends that document to another endpoint. If that other endpoint fails, I still want to send the original document to my user.

Currently, if it fails, the user does not get the response.

I'm not entirely sure how to do it without issues.

In short, this is what needs to happen:

- try 1 {
- CREATE DOCUMENT
- try 2 inside try 1 {
- .SEND DOCUMENT TO ENDPOINT
- .IF SUCCESS, UPDATE DOCUMENT IN DB
- .IF NOT SUCCESSFUL: CONTINUE <-- FAILS HERE
- .} catch 2: Do not throw error, just console.error
- RETURN ORIGINAL DOCUMENT TO USER <-- Must not fail if try 2 fails!
- } Catch 1: Throw error in this one

````
try {
const document = await prisma.document.create(
            {
              data: { 
                 //...
               }
            },
          );

          try {
            //TRY OPTIONAL ENDPOINT
            const tryEndpoint = () => {
     
              return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                fetch(`${process.env.ENDPOINT}`, {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
                    SOAPAction: 'Insert',
                  },
                  body: body,
                })
                  .then((response) => {
                    return response.text();
                  })
                  .then((text) => {
                    parseString(text, function (err: any, result: any) {
                      if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                      }

                      console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
                      if (
                        result['SOAP-ENV:Envelope']?.['SOAP-ENV:Body']?.[0]?.[
                          'tns:Result'
                        ]?.[0]?.['tns:Status']?.[0] === 'OK'
                      ) {
                        console.log('OK');
                        resolve(true);
                      } else {
                        console.log('ERROR');
                        resolve(false);
                      }
                    });
                    return null;
                  })
                  .catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                  });
              });
            };
            //DO NOT STOP IF ENDPOINT FAILS
            const didSendToEnpoint = await tryEndpoint();
            if (didSendToEnpoint) {
              await prisma.document.update({
                where: { id: +id },
                data: {
                  didTryEndpoint: true,
                },
              });
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
           //MUST RETURN IF OPTIONAL ENDPOINT FAILS
          return personDocumentStatus;
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
          if (error instanceof Error) {
            throw new Error(error.message);
          }
        }
      },
    },
    ```

How should I modify this code?
````

Comment: I don't fully understand your code but I guess you may consider using `try...catch...finally` and put that "RETURN ORIGINAL DOCUMENT TO USER" inside `finally()`. [MDN try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: Good idea! I'll try that next week and tell you the results.